# Complex derivative and partial derivatives, question on notation.

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

It just struck me that the complex derivative of $f : \mathbb{C} \supset D \to \Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$ at $z_0 \in int(D)$ and the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ have nearly identical definitions ($D$ is connected):

$$\frac{df}{dz} (z_0) \equiv \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 +h)-f(z_0)}{h}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (z_0) \equiv \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 +h)-f(z_0)}{h}$$

the only difference being that in the first case, $h \in \mathbb{C}$, and in the second, $h \in \mathbb{R}$, that is the two symbols $\lim$ mean different things, as the first one is designed for a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and the other for a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. I haven't seen this addressed in any text I've read about the subject. It's usually avoided by using notation such as $f(x_0+iy_0)$ instead of $f(z_0)$ when defining partials. But tacitly we are using two different operations, both called $\lim$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but the "meta"-information related to the limit, namely the domain of $h$ is different. Generally
$$\lim_{h\to h_0} f(h) = L$$
Is an expression with a domain for $h$. This translates to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(h_n) = L \qquad | \qquad \forall \ D_h \supset (h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \to h \in D_h$$
$D_h$ is this meta-information. In case of $\partial_z, D_h = \mathbb C$ and in case of $\partial_x, D_h = \mathbb R$ (and in case of $\partial_y, D_h = i\mathbb R$).
Hope that clarifies things...

Answer (score 1):

If $U\subset \mathbb C$ is open and $f:U\to \mathbb C$  holomorphic (=differentiable in the complex sense), then at any $z_0\in U$ we have the equalities $$\frac{df}{dz} (z_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (z_0)=\frac 1i  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (z_0) \quad (\in \mathbb C)$$ the second equality  being equivalent (once one decomposes $f$ into its real and imaginary parts as $f=u+iv$) to the Cauchy-Riemann equations.